# Pre-select option in a filter-horizontal from URL in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

first post here! I am trying to pre-select an option in a filter-horizontal I added to the change_form of my model. The id of the option to pre-select is in the url. How would I go to retrieve it in the **init** method of my form?

I saw this link, [retrieve url in init](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11645972/3229644), but considering that the form is instantiated automatically by the admin, it does not seem to fit the bill. (Unless I'm missing something?)

Here's my code.

```
class Section(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group', related_name='sections')

class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    //Adding a filter-horizontal to the 
    sections = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Section.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
            verbose_name=('Sections'),
            is_stacked=False
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Group

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['sections'].initial = self.instance.sections.all()
        else:
            //How-to...
            //Retrieve sectionID from URL and add to initial
            self.fields['sections'].initial = …

    def save(…)
        //saving the selected sections
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

I managed to do what I wanted via jQuery, but I would like to know if there is a way to do it in the init method…

edit: Here's my current JS snippet, just in case it could be of use to someone… Basic jquery, but anyway…

```
function getFromURI(URI, paramName) {
    var hash;
    if(paramName != undefined){
        URI = URI.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < URI.length; i++){
            hash = URI[i].split('=');

            if (hash[0] == paramName)
                return hash[1]
        }
    }
    return null
}

var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
var id = getFromURI(unescape(q), 'sectionId')

$('#id_sections_from option[value="' + id + '"]').detach().appendTo('#id_sections_to')
```

Comment: Another way - use thread locals to get request, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227180/why-is-using-thread-locals-in-django-bad

Comment: Thanks, this is something I did not know about. Not sure I wanna go down that road though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, searching for something different, I fell upon [this great answer by Chris Pratt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11569100/3229644) which is exactly what I was looking for at the time.

Turns out that 'request' is accessible through kwargs...

Leaving this here as an answer anyway...